# .htaccess: How are slashes (/) in RewriteRule handled?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here is my entire .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~user/sitetest/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ view.php?id=$1
```

When I access http://localhost/~user/sitetest/abc123, it loads the $_GET["id"] value and everything works fine. It's brilliant!

But I wanted it to work at http://localhost/~user/sitetest/view/abc123 (notice "view/")

So I tried replacing the `RewriteRule` with:

```
 RewriteRule ^view/(.+?)/?$ view.php?id=$1
```

But to no avail! It doesn't seem to load the $_GET[] from view.php. I even tried echoing out the $_GET[] value but it shows up as blank when I access http://localhost/~user/sitetest/view/abc123

So I edited it to see if this would work:

```
RewriteRule ^view-(.+?)/?$ view.php?id=$1
```

And it does when I access http://localhost/~user/sitetest/view-abc123 (notice the "-" instead of a "/")

So does it have something to do with the slash?? I am lost and have been struggling to figure this out.

**EDIT:**

I'm still having problems, but I noticed when I tried:

```
 RewriteRule ^test/(.+)/?$ view.php?id=$1
```

And accessed http://localhost/~user/sitetest/test/abc123 it worked!
So there seems to be a conflict with "view.php" and "view/" .. so in the worst case I'll rename view.php. But I'd still like to figure out what exactly is going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`view` in the requested url clashes with the `view.php` file, if MultiViews is enabled.

Disabled it with `Options -MultiViews` in your htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's where you're using `(.+?)` - try using just `(.+)`

Comment: If you have a physical folder called view, I guess that might throw it (although it shouldn't!)

Comment: Nope, no folder called view. I'm so lost haha.

Comment: Actually, creating a folder named `view` will fix it. But that is because multiviews will no longer try to match `view` to `view.php`. Better to just disable multiviews though.

Comment: You'll get there. Sometimes best to go get a cuppa, it'll be obvious when you get back!

Answer (score -1):

you can escape the slash after view like this view/ but I'm not sure if that solves the problem as slash is a path separator. So I think what you're trying to achieve will be better doing with some rule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+\/)(.+\/)$ page.php?p=$1&id=$2
```

and then you include your page from page.php with a simple php include($_GET['p']);

Comment: a `/` is not a reserved character in RegEx!

Comment: Agree :) sorry for that... anyway, i don't think path part can be successfully passed as a regex matched variable in mod_rewrite, do you?